# 404 on API request to admin token

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api

I'm making a request to integration/admin/token using the below code :

```
$response = $this->_client->request('POST', 'integration/admin/token', [
                'json' => [
                    'username' => $_stores[$store_id]['username'],
                    'password' => $_stores[$store_id]['password'],
                ],
            ]);
```

but here i am getting this error :

```
<XMLFile>
<Responses>
<Response>
<Type>Error</Type>
<Message>[WebScript] Client error: `POST XXX/index.php/rest/all/V1/integration/admin/token` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: <html> <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head> <body> <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center> <hr><center>nginx</c (truncated...) </Message>
</Response>
</Responses>
</XMLFile>
```

I am using the same script on many other Magneto instances with the same setup on the same server so i can't seem to figure out what i'm missing here, it's something i use quite often.

Comment: seems like an nginx problem. do you also use index.php when you want to view the storefront?

Comment: No, this is a file that integrates with another piece of software, but i'm usually able to view it